# Partial derivatives a function

Tags: calculus

I need to find the partial derivative of the function:

$$F(a,b) = \int_a^b\sqrt{t^3+1}\, \mathrm{d}t.$$

I can figure out how to get the partial derivative but I'm not sure how to simplify the function from a to b. How can I integrate this function?

Comment: Simply use the fundamental theorem of calculus. You do not need to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If
$$
G(t)=\int\sqrt{t^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
then
$$
\int_a^b\sqrt{t^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}t=G(b)-G(a)
$$